# iOS App Submitting failed

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I developed a apple application and actively running for almost a year. As per our design and rules, users **can only download** and use our app trough iphone (mobile).

Now, Im uploading another binary because of some update and it was declined. For the reason which is "The design has a lower quality from ipad".

Wait, the app is for iphone only, why are they reviewing it for ipad? nobody can install or seethe app using ipad except the developers. Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: All iPhone-only apps have always worked as-is on iPads. Apple has never allowed iPhone-only apps to prevent them being run on iPads.

Comment: Once check what you have set in 'Devices' dropdown under 'Deployment Info' in your project. It must be set to 'iPhone' if you want to target your app only for iPhones.

Comment: @rmaddy so how about apps with capabilities of sending sms and receiving calls? those are obviously not working with ipad.

Comment: @raki yep, that's exactly what i did. That is why Im asking why they test it with ipad.

Comment: iPads can send SMS. And there are iPads with cellular data too.